# Is it possible to translate folder names?

Tags: localization, folder

Is it possible to translate folders in SharePoint 2010?

I know a lot of things are translated OOTB in SP2010 after installing language packs (like content types, columns, document library names etc... What about folders, it seems they are not translatable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean folders in lists or folders in SharePoint root?
Folders in lists are content and not translated OOTB. 
Folders in SharePoint root aren't translated either. Language specific items are stored in a subfolder with the language code.

Regards, Anita